# What's the ruby way of doing this?

Tags: ruby, regex

I wrote something like this just now, and know there has to be a prettier way of doing this.

```
if REGEX.match(foostring) 
   match = REGEX.match(foostring)
   #do things with match data
end
```

Anybody know?

Comment: I tried "if match = /regex/.match(string)" but it threw up on me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better solution is to use regex match with block

```
string.match(/regex/) do |match|
  ...
end
```

That's the ruby way!

Note that, you can access the match by global variable `$1` as well, when you run `string.match(/regex/)`.

Comment: I was wondering if ruby had the $cap notation, That's awesome.

Comment: if you use named capture groups, you can write even better code

"hello little world".match(/hello (?<foo>.*)/) do |match|
  puts match[:foo]
end

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
/<reg_exp>/.match('foostring') do |match|
   #do things with match data
end
```

[Regexp#match](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html#method-i-match)

> Returns a `MatchData` object describing the match, or `nil` if there was no match. If a block is given, invoke the block with MatchData if match succeed

Comment: Oh. I guess I must have messed up something with the regex and got an error when I tried that. Thanks!